# Google Calendar API Service User

Tags: php, api, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

this is literally giving me nightmares!  I'm working with Google API for the first time.  I want to allow a website to add a calendar event to my calendar, without authentication.

From reading a LOT of tutorials, I've gathered that I need to access as a 'Service User'.  I've put together some code based on online examples, but it just isn't working, and I'm not getting any useful errors as to why!  It's not that I can't add to the calendar - I can't even get THAT far, it just seems to error as soon as the script calls the first Google API class.

```
    <?php

ini_set('include_path', '/home/sites/mysite.co.uk/public_html/testsite');

include "/google/src/Google/Client.php";
include "/google/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php";

echo "includes OK";

// Service Account info
//$calName = '####@group.calendar.google.com';
$client_id = '####';
$service_account_name = 'account-1@###.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = '/google/####.json';

if (!strlen($service_account_name) || !strlen($key_file_location))
        echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
    echo "ok so far";
    $client = new Google_Client();
    echo "ok call to Google";

    $client->setApplicationName("MyApp");
```

As you can see I've added some basic debugging to try to work out where the problem is.  So when I run the file, it gets as far as 'ok so far' and ever seems to get to 'ok call to Google'.  Sooo, I'm assuming it's something to do with my credentials?

1 - Do I need to update Client.php in the google api files?
2 - I am not 100% sure which credentials go where.  I've created an API key and a service account in Google Developers Console, but I am confused.  I've also given full access in the calendar sharing to the service account email address.

Any help would be really appreciated. 
Nicky

Comment: Check this documentation on how to authenticate the service account with assertions: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

Comment: That wasn't the problem.  My authentication was fine.  There was a problem locating the include files, which although they weren't erroring, updating my php ini file to output errors showed that something was wrong there.  Thanks for your help.